# Formatação de valores na casa de milhões

Tags: java

Quero formatar valores na casa de milhões. Exemplo:

O resultado de um calculo seria `1.960,35`. Mas a saida fica `19603565.2315789`.

Eu vinha utilizando `DecimalFormat`, mas era para números menores. Como fazer isso na casa de milhões?

Comment: Como está fazendo?Adicione o código na pergunta.

Comment: O duro é achar, mas já tem algumas respostas que mostram isso. De qualquer mostra o código que está usando.

Comment: Esse "." no número exemplo que citou está no lugar certo? Não seria 1960.35652315789?

Comment: Mostre o código e explique por que não está conseguindo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar a classe `NumberFormat`, para formatar.
Exemplo:

```
    double num = 12345678.90;
    Locale ptBr = new Locale("pt", "BR"); //define a região
    NumberFormat moeda = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(ptBr);
    System.out.print(moeda.format(num));
```

Ou tudo em uma linha:

```
System.out.print(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(ptBr).format(num));
```

Comment: Desculpem a demora para responder. @Iron Man, é isso mesmo q eu precisava. Dando mais uma pesquisada eu vi esse NumberFormat, mas não sabia dessa opçao Locale(ptBr), o resultado só saía em dólares. Muito obrigado.